Fatal Exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lkotlinx/serialization/internal/EnumsKt;
We are using a 3rd party library whose code is based on kotlin multiplatform and our project has a Groovy DSL. When I added the library and calls their methods my app is crashing. How can I fix the same. Please see the image of the crashlog received in firebase crashlytics. I am not sure if it is issue from our code or from 3rd party library. Can anyone help us here

The two steps for adding support for kotlinx serialization:
1) Add Gradle plugin
Groovy DSL:
plugins {
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.multiplatform' version '2.0.0'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.serialization' version '2.0.0'
}

2) Add library dependency
Groovy DSL:
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}


commonMain {
    dependencies {
        implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-core:1.7.1"
        implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-json:1.7.1"
    }
}


Reference:
https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization?tab=readme-ov-file#gradle
